# Django rest api validate data sent in the requests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a Django rest api to allow my clients to send requests with data, so that I can save them to a db. I have done that part but other than the format validation achieved through Serializers I also want check for data validation.... for example

```
UnitOfMeasureName = ["Each", "Grams", "Ounces", "Pounds", "Kilograms", "Metric Tons"]
```

**UnitOfMeasureName** should be one of the above in the list,

So if a user sends `{..., 'UnitOfMeasureName': 'invalid_one', ...}` in request data I want to send a bad request.
(This will pass the serializer as the type is string)

Any ideas please, If you need any clarification please ask in the comments. And thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your serializer class add a method to validate `UnitOfMeasureName` like following:

```
def validate_unitofmasurename(self, value):
    UnitOfMeasureName = ["Each", "Grams", "Ounces", "Pounds", "Kilograms", "Metric Tons"]
    if value in UnitOfMeasureName:
        return True
    else:
        return ValidationError('Invalid masure name')
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. What do you suggest if I have several fields as such to validate?

Comment: It depends on what kind of validation do you need. I recommend reading drf document http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/. You will understand your need.